# why does sailsjs use PUT for updates instead of PATCH

Tags: javascript, rest, sails.js

The Sails.js docs state that their route blueprint system will map PUT requests to update records.

However, I thought that PUT should only be used for a complete replacement of the record and not for partial updates.

I therefore think that PATCH would be the correct mapping.

This does not only apply to sails.js but also to many other REST examples where PUT is always mentioned as the update method.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: if there is a reason why people/sails use put for partial updates even though the spec advises otherwise

Comment: the only practical reason is no PATCH method support on ie8 and below. But the main reason, I think, is that nobody cares that much about the clarity of their REST. In the end of the day, REST is just a recommendation and not a restriction.